# Trigger action on button press on raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want to trigger an action on button press whatever I'm doing in the program. This button press have to change a global value necessary to do some different action based on this value. In the while loop I'm reading from RFID module if a valid card are detected. When I press the button without reading a card, the program runs well, but when I detect a card, the button doesn't trigger my callback function.

Here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/cvtehZyZ

Comment: removing line with os.system() works, I'm sure this is the problem...

Comment: I've solved this using subprocess.call().